# Extend a model with pydantic

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic, aws-lambda-powertools

Just started working with Pydantic models and have a question about extending existing model.

Assume that I want to put the `ServiceNowEvent` and `ServiceNowEventModel` into a package to make them available via simple imports.

The `ServiceNowEvent` contains key's that are always available in the event. But in different cases I want additional keys beeing available that I can define just on the fly.

```
class ServiceNowEvent(BaseModel):
    """ServiceNow Event Schema."""

    short_description: str
    description: str
    sys_id: str
    request: str
    ...
    

class ServiceNowEventModel(APIGatewayProxyEventModel):
    body: ServiceNowEvent

    @validator("body", pre=True)
    def transform_body_to_dict(cls, value: str) -> Any:
        return json.loads(value)
```

I can extend the body by simply inherting `ServiceNowEvent`, but then I´d need to change the type of body in `ServiceNowEventModel`. Like here:

```
class CustomServiceNowFields(ServiceNowEvent):
    my_custom_field: str


class ServiceNowEventModel(APIGatewayProxyEventModel):
    body: CustomServiceNowFields

    @validator("body", pre=True)
    def transform_body_to_dict(cls, value: str) -> Any:
        return json.loads(value)
```

Is there a way to keep `ServiceNowEventModel` untouched and directly append `my_custom_field` to `ServiceNowEvent` ?

Comment: Can you share a code example you are going to use to test results? I mean what data are you going to pass to model validator?